# calculate value to input for sound delay in a assembly program

Tags: assembly, audio, delay, cortex-m, armv7

I was looking at a program that is about a sound note sequencer that plays different sound notes with different duration, in the middle of some sound notes there will be a delay for like 0.5s or 0.25s, then I cannot figure out a way to calculate the value to load into the register to achieve the duration that I want.

I have searched wiki and some other online resoures such as from this website : https://www.avr-tutorials.com/assembly/calculating-execution-time-sequential-code to find out how to calculate the execution time for a function.

```
delay:
  push {lr}
  ldr r10, =12000 @ in fact this function will result in a delay of 0.25s
  b loop
```

```
loop:
  ..... @ some instructions to play sound
  subs r10, #1 @ in each loop the time counter is subtracted by 1
  cmp r10, #0 @ when time counter reaches zero, branch to a end function
  beq end
  b loop @ loop the function until time counter hits zero
```

for example, the above function with register `r10` as a time counter, and in another `loop` function,a value of `0`(meaning 0 Hz sound is input into the `register` to create a delay between sound notes) is added to register `r0` by `mov r0, #0`, and the I want to find out what value do I need to load into the time counter `r10` in order to let me play the 0 Hz sound for like `0.5s` or `0.25s` and how do I calculate this value to be loaded in. I don't know what is the exact way of saying this but perhaps I will phrase it as " calculating delay time in a program?"

The `delay` function that I found somewhere else will in fact really result in a `0.25s` delay but I don't understand how does it work. I am guessing it takes 0.25s for the time counter `r10` to reach 0 by subtracting 1 from it in each loop. But I really cannot figure out how does this calculation comes about.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just answering on `..in fact really result in a 0.25s delay but I don't understand how does it work` part (in fact, this is the only question I can recognise as a question):

A CPU instruction takes some fixed time to execute(*) on a given CPU clocked at a given frequency. Knowing this data you can calculate the number of loop iterations necessary to get the delay you need. It's just a simple arithmetic task.

(*) This does not hold for most modern CPUs and this method of implementing a delay is strongly discouraged for a number of reasons.

Comment: It actually does hold for Cortex-M; it's a very short simple in-order *scalar* pipeline, and you can look up the cycle count for each instruction.  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/BABBCJII.html#ftn.id4044496.  Delay-loops are usable for short delays on Cortex-M or AVR or other microcontrollers if you need very precise sleeps, especially for short intervals.  I wouldn't recommend it for something as long as 0.25s though!  That's plenty of time to go into a low-power sleep.